# Why does nested ifelse create incorrect results in dplyr 0.5.0 mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the following data frame:

```
(tmp_df <-
structure(list(class = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), logi = c(TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), val = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    taken = c(1.00684931506849, 0.993197278911565, 1.025, 0.975609756097561, 
    1.00826446280992, 0.991803278688525)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .Names = c("class", 
"logi", "val", "taken")))
```

which creates:

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 4]

  class  logi   val     taken
  <int> <lgl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1     0  TRUE     1 1.0068493
2     0 FALSE     1 0.9931973
3     1  TRUE     1 1.0250000
4     1 FALSE     1 0.9756098
5     2  TRUE     1 1.0082645
6     2 FALSE     1 0.9918033
```

I wish to group by class, and if each group contains two members, then subtract 1 from `val` if `logi == FALSE`, otherwise, subtract the minimum value of `taken` in that group from `val`. If each group does not contain two members, then we subtract zero from `val`.

Code using `dplyr` package to do the above can be expressed using:

```
tmp_df %>%
    group_by(class) %>%
    mutate(taken_2 = ifelse(n() != 2, 0, 
                              ifelse(logi, min(taken), 1)),
           not_taken = val - taken_2)
```

However, this produces the incorrect result, where by the second `ifelse` **always resolves to the first condition**:

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 6]
Groups: class [3]

  class  logi   val     taken   taken_2   not_taken
  <int> <lgl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
1     0  TRUE     1 1.0068493 0.9931973 0.006802721
2     0 FALSE     1 0.9931973 0.9931973 0.006802721
3     1  TRUE     1 1.0250000 0.9756098 0.024390244
4     1 FALSE     1 0.9756098 0.9756098 0.024390244
5     2  TRUE     1 1.0082645 0.9918033 0.008196721
6     2 FALSE     1 0.9918033 0.9918033 0.008196721
```

The correct result can be produced if we do not have the first `ifelse` statement.

```
tmp_df %>%
    group_by(class) %>%
    mutate(taken_2 = ifelse(logi, min(taken), 1),
           not_taken = val - taken_2)
```

producing:

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 6]
Groups: class [3]

  class  logi   val     taken   taken_2   not_taken
  <int> <lgl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
1     0  TRUE     1 1.0068493 0.9931973 0.006802721
2     0 FALSE     1 0.9931973 1.0000000 0.000000000 # correct!
3     1  TRUE     1 1.0250000 0.9756098 0.024390244
4     1 FALSE     1 0.9756098 1.0000000 0.000000000 # correct!
5     2  TRUE     1 1.0082645 0.9918033 0.008196721
6     2 FALSE     1 0.9918033 1.0000000 0.000000000 # correct!
```

We can see that this problem seems to be isolated to `mutate` and the nested `ifelse` by examining other code fragments that successfully do similar stuff:

```
tmp_df %>%
    group_by(class) %>%
    mutate(taken_2 = ifelse(n() != 3, 0, 
                            ifelse(logi, min(taken), 1)),
           not_taken = val - taken_2)

tmp_df_2 <-
    tmp_df %>%
    filter(row_number() <= 2)

(tmp_df_2$taken_2 <-
    ifelse(c(0, 0), 0, 
           ifelse(tmp_df_2$logi, min(tmp_df_2$taken), 1)))

## but the following does not work (checks problem is not to do with grouping)
# tmp_df_2 %>%
#     mutate(taken_2 = ifelse(n() != 2, 0, 
#                             ifelse(logi, min(taken), 1)),
#            not_taken = val - taken_2)
```

Why is this happening, and <s>how can I obtain the expected behaviour</s>? A workaround is to split the nested `ifelse` logic into multiple in-line mutates:

```
tmp_df %>%
    group_by(class) %>%
    mutate(taken_2 = ifelse(n() != 2, 0, 1),
           taken_3 = taken_2 * ifelse(logi, min(taken), 1),
           not_taken = val - taken_3)
```

Someone else has identified a similar problem with nested ifelse but I don't know whether it has the same root:
[ifelse using dplyr results in NAs for some records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38385302/ifelse-using-dplyr-results-in-nas-for-some-records)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are a victim of `ifelse` vector-recycling. They key is this line:

```
mutate(taken_2 = ifelse(n() != 2, 0, 
                          ifelse(logi, min(taken), 1))
```

Because `n() != 2` is length-1 (for each group), `ifelse` only considers the first `logi` and repeats/recycles this value.

You should use `if` and `if_else`:

```
mutate(taken_2 = if (n() != 2) 0 else if_else(logi, min(taken), 1))
```

I would recommend **never** to use `ifelse`. Take it from someone who almost caused a multi-million dollar error due to this exact bug.

Comment: thanks for your recommendation. `ifelse` was the only way of doing conditional mutates before those functions became available.

Comment: Indeed. But now `if_else` is available, you should use it -- and be grateful it is so fussy!

Comment: Also, same comment as I made to @Weihuang, how do you know that the result of the first `ifelse` is length one?

Comment: You're right that the documentation could be improved. But from `?n`, the title is '**The** number of observations in the current group'. So there can only be one observation.

Comment: The near multi-million dollar error sounds like a good story.

Comment: It's actually pretty dull: calculated payment due on table of clients. Used an ifelse condition -- only the condition for the first client in the table was considered.

Answer (score 3):

From `?ifelse`,

> `‘ifelse’ returns a value with the same shape as ‘test’`

and since `n() != 2` returns a vector of length one, and is always true, the second `ifelse` always returns a vector of length one, but is recycled to fit the shape of the group.  One solution is to feed a vector of the length of the group into the first `ifelse`:

```
tmp_df %>%
    group_by(class) %>%
    mutate(taken_2 = ifelse(rep(n() != 2, n()), 0, 
                              ifelse(logi, min(taken), 1)),
           not_taken = val - taken_2)
# Source: local data frame [6 x 6]
# Groups: class [3]

#   class  logi   val     taken   taken_2   not_taken
#   <int> <lgl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1     0  TRUE     1 1.0068493 0.9931973 0.006802721
# 2     0 FALSE     1 0.9931973 1.0000000 0.000000000
# 3     1  TRUE     1 1.0250000 0.9756098 0.024390244
# 4     1 FALSE     1 0.9756098 1.0000000 0.000000000
# 5     2  TRUE     1 1.0082645 0.9918033 0.008196721
# 6     2 FALSE     1 0.9918033 1.0000000 0.000000000
```

Comment: thanks. I thought `n()` would produce a value for each row, but evidently it only does when explicitly assigned as such, e.g. `num_in_row = n()`. I was trying to get away without creating that extra variable and it caught me out.

Comment: How do you know that `n() = 2` always returns a vector of length one anyway, since the documentation for `n()` is exceedingly succint.

Comment: You're right, I don't actually know `n() == 2` returns a vector of length one; I inferred it from its behavior.

Comment: Yes, `n()` returns a vector of length one: `mtcars %>% summarise(x = length(n()))` so `n() == 2` is length one. If you assign `n()` to a variable, it gets recycled, e.g. `mtcars %>% mutate(x = n())`

Comment: thanks @alistaire, that changes the way I think about `n()` now.